# Gupta Centura/Team Developer guides/manuals/book

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

In our company use Centura from 1999, I'm newbie in this, but there not so lot information on web, can somebody help me with good manuals? I find this language looks like Ada.

Comment: 'Centura' used to be the generic term used for Gupta SQLWindows / TeamDeveloper and associated toolset. Actually,  Centura only released one version of the toolset - v1.5. The toolset is now owned and developed by OpenText ( and is commonly referred to as Gupta ) and the latest release is v7.1 - which is native 64bit , UNICODE and .Net enabled.  Go here to see the OpenText Gupta Product Overview :  https://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-team-developer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good stuff. Moved on a lot since 1999.

SQLWindows is now 64bit ( version 7 onwards ) , UNICODE ( v5 onwards ) and .Net enabled.

Well there are many resources - you just need to know where to look.  Also there are many, many manuals  - I'll attach some here as a starter. If you need anything specific e.g. ReportWriter or Connectivity or DBA etc - just say and I will attach.

1) [Gupta / Centura Manuals (ALL versions !)](http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=Misc/TD_Books/)

Here are some other links you MUST have:

2) [Gupta Global Community Forum - ( Sign-in and you get more options )](http://forum.tdcommunity.net/)

3) [Archived Global Community Forum ( Read Only)](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/)

4) [Gupta Team Developer/SQLWindows Wiki](http://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/Main_Page)

5) [Team Developer Sample Vault](http://samples.tdcommunity.net/)

6) [TekTips Centura Forum](http://www.tek-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=430)  and [(another) TekTips Gupta Forum](http://www.tek-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=854)

7) [Gupta SQLWindows - SQLBase - TD.Net Users & Developers Network](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/144210)

Comment: Steve, where can I find docs for 5.07? I have some problems with UNICODE using( wiki doesn't help)

Comment: I will upload the Manual for 5.0 to the Gupta / Centura Manuals Site. Although the 5.1 manual should cover it. Otherwise you can either post the issue here, or post your question / issue to the TD Forum here:   http://forum.tdcommunity.net/  under the TeamDeveloper 5.x section,    and you will def. get help that way - as just about every UNICODE issue has been worked through by now .

Answer (score 0):

[Gupta technologies TD support documents for version 5.1](https://support.guptatechnologies.com/Docs/TDDoc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm)

The link contains features for version 5.1 but core concepts remains the same for all versions.

The link contains documentation for below mentioned modules,

```
1. Team Developer Web Services

2. Team Developer - API Reference

3. Connecting SQLWindows Objects to Databases

4. Extending the SQLWindows Development Environment.

5. Localizing and Customizing SQLWindows Applications

6. Unify Report Builder - Business Reporting.

7. Managing Teams and Objects with Team Object Manager
```

Comment: Your link only references TD5.1   .   Misleading I think , as the request specifically mentions Centura ( which is TD 1.5.1 ) , and we are now up to version 7.1  .  Also your link is just a subset / repetition of the link already given earlier.

Comment: thanks for your comments! kindly note the question is not specific to version 7.1. And is not a repetition of links listed by you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a guy that made some videos on YouTube teaching Gupta.

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNQmauumXnBc_kS9cyUJ3d3u2nNWXms0z

He also wrote a book CDT2000 and share for free a actualized version on web.

http://appstartup.blogspot.com/2013/05/?m=0

Tks LairtonJr.

Comment: There are thousands of YouTube videos on the entire Gupta Toolset. Just search for 'Gupta Team Developer. or 'Gupta SQLBase'. And they are in English.