# What is functional class in Centura?

Tags: class, functional-programming, centura

I am a new programmer in Centura, I am familiar with the concept of class from C++ or JAVA but I am little bit confused with functional classes in context of windows. Can somebody explain me, what is it and how its works? Thank you

Comment: Yes in Centura Developer, my confusion arise from misunderstanding, why there is something like functional class, when i can create an object with methods. What are the differences between functional class and "normal" class?

Comment: The subject is greater than can be explained here. Go to:  https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=Misc/TD_Books/    to download which ever set of manuals is applicable to the version you are running, and the most comprehensive explanation of Functional Classes ( and other types ) is in 'dev.pdf' manual.   p.s. 'Centura' has been called 'Gupta Technologies Team Developer', or 'SQLWindows', or 'TD.Net' for about the last 20 years.

Comment: If you would like, here are some v. useful Gupta ( Centura ) resources you cannot live without : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371432/gupta-centura-team-developer-guides-manuals-book

Comment: @MiroslavSavel Main difference is that functional class doesnot have a message action section but a normal class(window class) have that.

Comment: Also, Functional Classes can be passed around as parameters or UDV's, so the functional class can (say) simply be a data structure  - declare the functional class as a UDV User Defined Variable , and pass it as a parameter. That way the entire Functional Class instance gets passed  Saves passing each individual variable. Magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional class is used to,

1.Create user defined variables.

2.Define behavior(functions) that is shared by more than one window class.

Functional class can be created by right clicking the Classes folder of Teamdeveloper and then select new functional class from the popup menu.

[image]

A functional class can be,

1. Base class of another functional class.
2. Base class of a window class.
3. Derived from another functional class, but not from a window class

If behavior needs to be shared by more than one window type, you can place the behavior in a functional class and 
then derive window classes from that functional class. The derived classes inherit the common behavior as well as 
behavior appropriate to their window type.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is greater than can be explained here. Go to: [Gupta TeamDeveloper Manuals](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=Misc/TD_Books/)    to download which ever set of manuals is applicable to the version you are running, and the most comprehensive explanation of Functional Classes ( and other types ) is in 'dev.pdf' manual.   p.s. 'Centura' has been called 'Gupta Technologies Team Developer', or 'SQLWindows', or 'TD.Net' for about the last 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

create a program show user enter name of day get day from user check if day is Monday ="check day" tuseday="bicep day" wednesday="tricep day" thurs day="lnirgs day" friday ="heg day" saturday="Abs day"  Sunday ="rest day " show user what exercise he was to on that day